# Why this problem setup seems to violate conservation of momentum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, energy-conservation

**Problem:**

An object $A$ with mass $m_A=2$ kg is at rest with velocity $v_A=0$ m/s. A second object $B$ with mass $m_B=1$ kg approaches it with velocity $v_B=3$ m/s. $B$ slides over $A$ and pulls it across due to friction. Half of its kinetic energy is lost as heat due to friction. How do I find the final velocity of the pair after this encounter assuming both objects have the same final velocity?

**Solution:**

Let $E$ denote the kinetic energy given by $E=\dfrac{1}{2}mv^2$.

$E_{A0}=0$, $E_{B0}=4.5$ J

$\Longrightarrow$ $E_{0}= 0+4.5$ J

After frictional encounter, the new velocity is same for both objects.

$E_1=2.25$ J

$E_1=\dfrac{1}{2}(m_A+m_B)v_1^2$

$2.25=\dfrac{1}{2}3\,v_1^2$

$1.5=v_1^2 =>v_1=1.22474487$ m/s

Thus, final velocity of $m_A$ and $m_B$ is 1.22474487 m/s.

What is wrong with this problem/solution? I know something is but I can't figure out what it is. Can this scenario never occur or the momentum conservation is being violated?

Comment: Where did you use conservation of total momentum? Or did you use something else that you mistakenly thought is consistent with conservation of total momentum?  So, what happens immediately after the collision? and why?

Comment: Initial momentum of the two bodies above is: $3+0 => 3 Kg.m/sec$. The final momentum of the system above is: $1.22474487 * (1+2) => 3.67423461 Kg.m/sec$. So the momentum is unequal. I used the conservation of energy but that should give the same result as the conservation of momentum since both are conservation laws?

Comment: @robphy can you please explain the issue. If you mean the momentum is conserved as the two objects collide and bounce in opposite directions so one sign is -ve and other is +ve then we are not taking about collision as one object is at rest and second is moving in +ve direction and drags the first due to friction not direct collision (so they will if i am correct move in the same direction i.e. +ve) so the sign issue will not arise. can you please explain?

Comment: Either you assume half the kinetic energy is lost or that they have same final velocity. Not both. The two conditions are not compatible. Or there is some unknown third object interacting with them during collision.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose two objects with masses $m_A$ and $m_B$ collide and stick together, with $m_A$ initially at rest and $m_B$ having an initial velocity $v$.  If momentum is conserved, then it is not too hard to show (try it!) that the ratio of the kinetic energy after the collision to the kinetic energy before the collision must be
$$
\frac{E_f}{E_i} = \frac{m_B}{m_A + m_B}.
$$
More generally, it can also be shown for a fixed initial velocity of $m_B$, $E_f$ is minimized when the blocks stick together after the collision. So if we relax the condition that the blocks stick together, we must have in general
$$
\frac{E_f}{E_i} \geq \frac{m_B}{m_A + m_B}.
$$

In your case, with $m_A = 2 m_B$, this implies that you must have $E_f/E_i \geq 1/3$, with $E_f/E_i = 1/3$ if the blocks end up with the same final velocity.  This means that it is inconsistent to require all three of the following statements to be true:

- Half of the kinetic energy is lost as heat in the collision.
- Momentum is conserved in the collision.
- The blocks stick together in the collision.

One of these three statements must be false.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. But if we take the "half kinetic energy is lost as heat" as the actual setup the total final momentum of the: [two masses + photons emitted as heat] should be equal to the initial momentum. Is that correct? As, I used the conservation of energy above and the momentum of the two bodies seem to be greater than the two bodies before collision. But that cannot be the case! Does that mean the photons emitted have -ve momentum to contribute to this equation so that: [Initial Momentum of two bodies = Final Momentum of two bodies + Momentum of Photons]?

Comment: Can you please help with the actual setup above i.e. numbers assuming half the energy is lost as heat. I am unclear how to proceed regarding photon momentum vs. their energy etc. (I know the total energy lost, they seem to have very little momentum, but how do I calculate the number of photons and their momentum per photon from above). Is it even possible? I am terribly confused. We can assume all photons are of same wavelength (say 555 nanometers)

Comment: @student0:  "Heat" ("thermal energy", properly speaking) usually means a disordered energy.  If you need your photons to have a net momentum when they're emitted, then they don't really qualify as "heat".  What you're proposing is a situation where one block collides with another and emits an EM wave in the opposite direction in the process (thus giving you the "negative momentum" needed to balance the equation.)  This isn't terribly realistic.

Comment: Wrong terminology. Apologies. If an object 'slides over' (i am trying to avoid the word collision as it to me usually implies head on collision) another object (and both are free to move) eventually due to surface friction both will acquire same velocity. Wouldn't the generated radiation automatically balance the equation (since its a law of nature) if not half say some significant x% is lost as radiation. You suggest its unrealistic in the practical sense or is there a theoretical reason for it (I assume too much radiation required for balancing it ?)

Answer (score 0):

As I was looking at the numbers, I noticed the inconsistency that @Michael points out must be there.

In a 1d-collision, when given the masses and the initial velocities, the conservation of total momentum equation has two unknowns: the two final velocities.

We need more information to determine a unique solution to this problem.
One extra condition (one more equation) must be specified... so that we now have two equations with two unknowns.

- possibly, it's an elastic (total-kinetic-energy conserving) collision
- possibly, it's a totally-inelastic collision (a sticky collision)... so the final velocities are equal
- or some other condition, like specifying one (of the two) final velocities [possibly given implicitly]

An inconsistency can arise if we have two extra equations (instead of one) since we now have three equations with two unknowns.

Comment: the condition half the kinetic energy is lost as heat was the one that was given. How can we assume that and calculate the final velocities ? Or we cannot solve with that constraint?

Comment: @student0 "Half of its kinetic energy is lost"... who is "it"? So, what is the final velocity of "it"?

Comment: it would be the system and its initial kinetic energy: of mass A and B. And the final velocity of A and B (assuming they are different).

Comment: @student0 If C loses energy, then "C and D" loses energy. But did D lose energy? Focus on who loses energy and find its final velocity, then use that to find the other final velocity.

Comment: I honestly am struggling to get it. Assume an object approaching and then travelling over another object. Some of the friction would generate a 'pull' in the traversing direction and rest of it would be lost as heat (again due to friction). Eventually they would have the same velocity. So some of the initial kinetic energy would be converted to heat and rest would be transferred to the static object. That was essentially what i had in mind when i said their final velocities are same. is there something wrong in this approach?

Comment: secondly only if we have a single constraint: "half of the total initial kinetic energy is lost as heat" without assuming anything about their final velocities how do we calculate their final velocities?

Comment: @student0 We have momentum-conservation (two unknown final velocities) and the single-constraint (one of the unknown final velocities). Solve the system of equations. (Try it.) In general (and in your case), the final velocities are unequal (think of this collision as a grazing collision) ... so it is a mistake to assume it if you use the half-of-kinetic-energy-loss-constraint.

Comment: there seem to be two values that satisfy the constraints: $V_{af}, V_{bf} = (1.5, 0) or (.5, 2).$ Is this correct?

Comment: @student0 Those pairs are two out of an infinite-number of pairs that satisfy the conservation of total momentum: $m_aV_{af}+m_bV_{bf}=m_a(0)+m_b(3)$. (Plotting $V_{bf}$-vs-$V_{af}$ will be a line.) Now you need another equation to encode the half-of-the-kinetic-energy-lost by B. (This will produce another curve on a plot on $V_{bf}$-vs-$V_{af}$.) The solution to your problem (the solution to this system of equations) is where these two curves intersect.